# Using abstract method in non-abstract class

Tags: java, abstract

I got the abstract class `ContentClass`

```
public abstract class ContentClass
{
    public abstract String getClassType();
    public abstract String getSortId();
}
```

And the non abstract class `Node`

```
public class Node <ContentClass>
{
    private ContentClass content;
    private Node left;
    private Node right;

    public Node(Node l, Node r,ContentClass c)
    {
        content = c;
        left = l;
        right = r;
    }

    public String getNodeSortId(){
    return content.getSortId();
    }
    public String getNodeType(){
    return content.getClassType();
    }
    public ContentClass getContent(){
        return content;
    }

    public Node getLeft(){
        return left;
    }

    public Node getRight(){
        return right;
    }
}
```

The problem at hand being that `content.getSortId()` and `content.getNodeType()` are both marked as "undeclared method".
How do I fix this and what did I do wrong?

I want to later on create non-abstract content classes that can contain different types of content and the class Node is supposed to be able to take in any contentclass as a variable

Comment: The type of field content is  `ContentClass` the generic parameter of `Node`, not your own class `ContentClass`. Do you want nodes to work with `ContentClass` only, or with any class?

Comment: `content::getSortId` is marked in the IDE, or you got a compiler error? And I suggest that you write `public class Node<C extends ContentClass>` and `private C content;` and `public C getContent() {…}`.

Comment: Node should only be able to take in a class that extends ContentClass as "Content" variable

Comment: are these classes in  the same package? Otherwise the methods must be `public` (it is always better to include a [mre] in such questions)

Comment: Use an interface not abstract class.

Comment: Sorry, my last comment is not (yet) relevant - You are declaring a `<ContentClass>` as  a type in `class Node <ContentClass>` (similar to `public class Node <T>` - `T` is NOT a class) - you probably want `class Node<T extends ContentClass>`, `private T content;`, `Node(Node l, Node r,T c)`, ... or no generics at all `public class Node {`

Comment: there is a implemented class "TermNode" already but the point of ContentClass variable content in Node is to act as a place holder for the actual content that will be passed on in the constructor when the code is run

Comment: Looks like an assignment to me. Is it? If so, then are you required to make class `Node` a generic class?

Comment: @EmilyHlífCarozzini If you want to know the actual subtype, then use bounds for the generic - `T extends ContentType`. Otherwise just remove the generic and directly make the field of type `ContentType`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misunderstood how a generic type is declared for a class.

`public class Node <ContentClass>` **does not** make use of the abstract class named ContentClass.  That line is actually declaring a brand new generic type identifier, which you happened to name `ContentClass`.  It has no relationship whatsoever to the abstract class named ContentClass.

If you look at, say, [List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) or [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html), you will see that they declare their generic argument type using a single capital letter:  `List<E>`, `Comparable<T>`.  Nearly all Java SE classes use this convention, and for good reason:  it greatly reduces the likelihood of making this kind of mistake.

What you probably want is this:

```
public class Node<C extends ContentClass>
{
    private C content;
    private Node left;
    private Node right;

    public Node(Node l, Node r, C c)
    {
        content = c;
        left = l;
        right = r;
    }

    // ...

    public C getContent() {
        return content;
    }
```

In the above code, `C` is the type argument.  Because it was declared as a type which must inherit from ContentClass, any object of type C is guaranteed to have the getClassType() and getSortId() methods.

Aside from the declaration of `C`, the name “ContentClass” should not appear anywhere in your Node class.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the way you're defining the generic class Node. You've defined Node to take a type parameter ContentClass, but it looks like you're trying to use it as if ContentClass is a class, rather than a type parameter. In your current code, ContentClass is being treated as a placeholder for a generic type, not as a reference to your ContentClass abstract class.

remove

```
<ContentClass>
```

from

```
public class Node <ContentClass>
    {
        private ContentClass content;
        private Node left;
```

this will solve your problem.